# Assign results of promise.all() in typescript

Tags: typescript, promise

I'm trying to assign the results of `Promise.all()` in typescript but somehow `Promise.all()` changes the return type to `number | <actual type>`, also when I try to do it inside `then()`...
Is there a way to do this?

[image: type error message]

Answer (score 1):

I figured the type change isn't from `Promise.all()` itself, but from the `catch` block which returns the result of `array.push()`.

Changing the error handling to:

```js
.catch(err => {
    errors.push(err);
    return {};
});
```

seems to solve this.